# difference between gzip compression and `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')`

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

what is difference between `ob_start()` and `ob_start('ob_gzhandler')` ?

and what's the use of these ? If I use `.htaccess` gzip compression then even too need of `ob_start()` in my code to increase speed of website

I have used following in my core.php file which will be called every time on every request.

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) {
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
} else {
    ob_start();
}
```

Also I have used `gzip` compression to compress files

Comment: `ob_gzhandler` just uses the `DEFLATE` format, without the extra `gzip` stream headers.

Comment: should i use both or not ?

Comment: There's no generic answer to this. Normally neither. Compression is nowadays handled by Apaches `mod_deflate`. And chunked transfers covered by FCGI commonly. Using `ob_start` is a poor workaround for other issues.

Comment: @mario Thanks for your support. One more thing 
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
?>

Instead of :
<?php
$content = '<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>';
?>

Is it correct way